Manhwa where the main character got swallowed by a drake
I remember reading a chapter where the main character got swallowed by a drake and then some people, sad because they thought he had died, came in a helicopter. Then the drake (or dragon) died and the main character came out of its stomach.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I about a one to two years ago, but I don’t remember where

"came sad"? I'm not certain what you mean.

They got to the place where he was sad because they thought he had died. (English is my second language so I’m not really good at it)

Ah. I suppose that makes sense with that context.
